# Have no idea to evaluate this integral with e

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate $\int\frac{e^{2x}}{4+e^{4x}}dx$

Have no idea to evaluate this integral with e

Comment: Let $u=e^{2x}$, $a=2$, then you have $$\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{du}{a^2+u^2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e^{2x}=u$. Then $e^{4x}=u^2$ and $du=2e^{2x}dx$.

Then we have $\frac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{du}{2^2+u^2}=\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(u/2)+C$. Now substitute back $e^{2x}$ for $u$

Comment: my professor use this as example and i messed up with my notes, so i still unable to do this.

Comment: @Victor: Ok- let me add details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hints